Two given ordinal numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfy one and only one of the relations $\alpha<\beta$, $\alpha=\beta$, $\alpha>\beta$.
I am studying Introductory Real Analysis by Kolmogorov and Fomin. First, some definitions:

Two isomorphic ordered sets are said to have the same (order) type;
The order type of a well-ordered set is called an ordinal.

My doubt arises at the start of the proof that two given ordinal numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfy one and only one of the relations $\alpha<\beta$, $\alpha=\beta$, $\alpha>\beta$. It starts as it follows. Let $W(\alpha)$ be the set of all ordinals $<\alpha$. Any two numbers $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ in $W(\alpha)$ are comparable and the corresponding ordering of $W(\alpha)$ makes it a well-ordered set of type $\alpha$.
To state that two numbers $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ are comparable shouldn't I use what I am trying to prove? Further, I cannot work out why this ordering would implies that it is a well ordered set (von Neumann construction is not mentioned).

i think this proof is using induction on ordinals.

Thanks for your reply. However, induction is introduced in the next section so it should not.

I suggest the following strategy:

Prove that no ordinal is isomorphic to its proper initial segment (hint: initial segments of an ordinal are obviously well-ordered).
Use this to show that if $\alpha$ is isomorphic to an initial segment of $\beta$, then the segment (and the isomorphism) are unique.
Consider the relation $\alpha\preceq\beta$ which says that $\alpha$ is isomorphic to an initial segment of $\beta$.
Observe that $\alpha\preceq\beta\preceq\alpha$ implies $\alpha=\beta$.
Show that $\alpha\preceq\beta$ or $\beta\preceq\alpha$.
Using the fact that $\alpha\prec \beta$ implies $\alpha<\beta$ and the preceding points, conclude that if $\alpha<\beta$, then $\alpha\prec \beta$.


You said $\alpha\preceq\beta$ means $\alpha$ is isomorphic to a proper initial segment of $\beta$. Did you mean $\alpha$ is isomorphic to $\beta$ or a proper initial segment of $\beta$?

@Lucenaposition: Yes, sorry, I meant to write "isomorphic to an initial segment of $\beta$ (not necessarily proper).
